# Safely uninstall a package in Gentoo

Tags: package-management, software-installation, gentoo, emerge

I wanted to uninstall a specific package in Gentoo and browsed through the emerge man page. I found the `--unmerge` option:

> **WARNING:  This action can remove important packages!** Removes all
>   matching packages.  This does no checking of dependencies, so it may
>   remove packages necessary for the proper operation of your system.Its
>   arguments can be atoms or ebuilds. For a dependency aware version of
>   **--unmerge**, use **--depclean** or **--prune**.

However, I'd like emerge to check whether the package I want to uninstall is required by any other installed package in the system. `--depclean` and `--prune` don't provide that functionality:

- `--depclean` removes packages that were installed as dependencies, but are not needed anymore
- `--prune` "removes all but the highest installed version of a package from your system"

Is there no dependency-checking version of `--unmerge`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think `depclean` works the way you described. Without any arguments it does, but if you pass it a package name it works like `unmerge` with an additional dependency check. From `emerge(1)`:

> Depclean serves as a dependency aware version of `--unmerge`. When given one or more atoms, it will unmerge matched packages that have no reverse dependencies. Use `--depclean` together with `--verbose` to show reverse dependencies.

I always use `--depclean` (`-c`) to unmerge individual packages; it works fine

Answer (score 6):

Another way to achieve the same result (although it's not a command that unmerges with dependency checking): `emerge --deselect package`, which removes the package from the world file. Now, running `emerge --depclean` will remove that package iff it's not required by any other package.

Comment: Does that mean that `emerge --depclean` removes all packages that were installed using `emerge --oneshot` (unless those packages are needed by a package from world)?

Comment: @danielkullmann yes. it computes the whole dependency graph and removes what's not pulled by any package in world. You can use `emerge --noreplace --select` to add already installed packages without recompiling them, btw.

Answer (score 6):

gentoolkit comes to help:

```
equery d <atom>
```

You can check dependencies first, then proceed to remove the package after inspecting its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, `emerge --unmerge` gives this warning message:

```
 * This action can remove important packages! In order to be safer, use
 * `emerge -pv --depclean <atom>` to check for reverse dependencies before
 * removing packages.
```

It seems that this is the recommended way to do dependency checking before unmerging a package. I still hope, though, that there is a better, more automated, way to achieve this.